# Problem parsing children of a node with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm having a problem parsing the input tag children of a form in html.  I can parse them from the root using //input[@type] but not as children of a specific node.

Here's some code that illustrates the problem:

```
private const string HTML_CONTENT =
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<title>Test Page</title>" +
        "<link href='site.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<form id='form1' method='post' action='http://www.someplace.com/input'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='test' />" +
        "<input type='text' name='something' value='something' />" +
        "</form>" +
        "<a href='http://www.someplace.com'>Someplace</a>" +
        "<a href='http://www.someplace.com/other'><img src='http://www.someplace.com/image.jpg' alt='Someplace Image'/></a>" +
        "<form id='form2' method='post' action='/something/to/do'>" +
        "<input type='text' name='secondForm' value='this should be in the second form' />" +
        "</form>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>";

public void Parser_Test()
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument
        {
            OptionFixNestedTags = true,
            OptionUseIdAttribute = true,
            OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
            OptionAddDebuggingAttributes = true
        };

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML_CONTENT);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true);
        var nodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form");
        if (nodeCollection != null && nodeCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var form in nodeCollection)
            {
                var id = form.GetAttributeValue("id", string.Empty);
                if (!form.HasChildNodes)
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Form {0} has no children", id ) );

                var childCollection = form.SelectNodes("input[@type]");
                if (childCollection != null && childCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Got some child nodes");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to find input nodes as children of Form");
                }
            }
            var inputNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input");
            if (inputNodes != null && inputNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} input nodes when parsed from root", inputNodes.Count ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found no forms");
        }
    }
```

What is output is:

```
Form form1 has no children
Unable to find input nodes as children of Form
Form form2 has no children
Unable to find input nodes as children of Form
Found 3 input nodes when parsed from root
```

What I would expect is that Form1 and Form2 would both have children and that input[@type] would be able to find 2 nodes for form1 and 1 for form2

Is there a specific configuration setting or method that I'm not using that I should be?  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've given up on HtmlAgilityPack for now.  Seems like there is still more work to do in that library to get everything working.  To solve this problem I've moved the code over to use the SGMLReader library from here: http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader

Using this library all my unit tests pass properly and the sample code works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this discussion thread on the HtmlAgilityPack site - 
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/21782

This is what they say:

> This is not a bug, but a feature and is configurable. FORM is treated like this because many HTML pages used to have overlapping forms, as this was actually a (powerful) feature of original HTML. Now that XML and XHTML exist, everybody assumes that overlapping is an error, but it's not (in HTML 3.2).
>   Check the HtmlNode.cs file, and modify the ElementsFlags collection (or do it at runtime if you prefer)

To modify the HtmlNode.cs file, comment out following line -

```
ElementsFlags.Add("form", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap | HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
```

Comment: For those who don't want to change Html Agility Pack code: HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

Comment: more on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason

Comment: I wish I could vote this up several times. This "feature" encourages falling into the pit of failure.