# Parsing HTML Reading Option Tag Content with HtmlAgillityPack

Tags: html, select, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML, but am having problems.

Sample HTML Doc:

```
<tr>
  <td class="css_lokalita" colspan="4">
    <select id="region" name="region">
      <option value="0"  selected>Všetky regiony</option>
      <optgroup>Banskobystrický kraj</optgroup>
      <option value="k_1"  style="color: #000000; font-weight:bold;">Banskobystrický kraj</option>
      <option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Banská Bystrica</option>
          .
          .
          .
      <option value="174">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CZ - Ústecký kraj</option>
      <option value="175">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CZ - Zlínský kraj</option>     
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="css_sfotkou"  colspan="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="foto" value="1" id="foto" />
    <label for="foto">Iba používatelia s fotkou</label>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="css_miestnost" colspan="4">
    <select name="akt-miest" id="onoffaci">
      <option value="a_0">Všetci</option>
          .
          .
          .
      <optgroup label="Záľuby a záujmy">
        <option value="m_1419307">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bez Lásky</option>
          .
          .
          .
        <option value="m_1108016">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drum N Bass</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need parse value from `<select name="akt-miest" id="onoffaci">`

For example:

```
<option value="**a_0**">**Všetci**</option>
```

I need get value `**a_0**` and text `**Všetci**`.

So I try first access to select by Id:

```
var selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("onoffaci");
```

Then with Xpath select all option node.

```
var nodes = selectNode.SelectNodes("//option");
```

And get values:

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string roomName = node.NextSibling.InnerText;
    string roomId = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
    rooms.Add(new Room { RoomId = roomId, RoomName = roomName });
}
```

But I get values from another select (`<select id="region" name="region">`) this select is on the top of html code.

**EDITED:**

I apply advice of Darin Dimitrov an try this:

```
HtmlNode selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("onoffaci");

var nodes = selectNode.SelectNodes("option");

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string roomName = node.NextSibling.InnerText;
    string roomId = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
    rooms.Add(new Room { RoomId = roomId, RoomName = roomName });
}

return rooms;
```

I parse only first three option element, because I think the problem is that select consist

optgroup tag.

```
<select name="akt-miest" id="onoffaci">
  <option value="a_0">Všetci</option>
  <option value="a_1">Iba prihlásení</option>
  <option value="a_5" selected="selected">Teraz na Pokeci</option>
  <optgroup label="Hlavné miestnosti">
    <option value="m_13">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bez záväzkov</option>
    <option value="m_9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do pohody</option>
    <option value="m_39">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dámsky klub</option>
  </optgroup>
  .
  .
  .
```

I try select all following node  with this

```
var nodes = selectNode.SelectNodes("option::*");
```

But I get this error: `xpath has an invalid token.`

I would like access to all childs of selectNode:

```
HtmlNode selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("onoffaci");
```

EDIT #2:

Here is it all html file, from which I need parse option tags.

http://hotfile.com/dl/98442053/577b556/source.html

Comment: @user572844: check my answer for a solution and explanation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, the `<OPTION>` tag is treated by Html Agility Pack as "Empty", which means it does not need a closing `</OPTION>`. In this case, the closing tag is discarded. You can change this behavior using the `HtmlNode.ElementFlags` collection.

Here is a code that should do what you want:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='onoffaci']//option"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value=" + node.Attributes["value"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("InnerText=" + node.InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I try your code but it select only first 3 option tag, maybe is problem that I didn’t show all html file. I edited my question on the botton is html file.

Comment: @user572844 - ok, I see what you mean, in fact there are options under other tags (optgroup), I have updated the code accordingly, I have replaced //select[@id='onoffaci']/option by //select[@id='onoffaci']//option (note the double / in front of option)

Comment: +1 and thank you for this answer - do you happen to know *why* this is the default behavior?  Are there any other tags this will happen for?

Comment: @AdamRackis - Yes I do, see here on SO for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason/4237224#4237224 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556089/html-agility-pack-removes-break-tag-close/5557297#5557297 (to have the full list of ElementFlags, just look at the source, it's open source)

Comment: Thank you.  So, if I'm only using HAP to load existing html, and move it some place else without changing it one bit, would I be better off removing **all** flags?

Comment: @AdamRackis - good question. It really depends on the HTML in question., so I don't have a definitive answer to that :-)

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I've got the option flag removed, so my option closing tags are being kept.  It doesn't look like it strips off closing tags for td elements (I checked since I've been told their closing tags are optional too) so the only change I can see is input img and br and probably a few others have /> changed to >, which shouldn't matter at all.  Is there any other gotcha I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression:

```
//option
```

It's an absolute path: it traverse all the tree **starting from the root**.

You need a relative XPath expression:

```
descendant::option
```

Or the shorthand

```
.//option
```

**Do note:** this is the **only** case where to start a path with `.` (`self::node()` shorthand) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
selectNode.SelectNodes("option");
```

instead of:

```
selectNode.SelectNodes("//option");
```

or you are starting your XPath expression from the root of the HTML document.

Comment: NO I start on select node, but I have problem because select tag consist also optgroup tag.