# Xpath select all child nodes

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need select all child nodes (option tag) from this html:

```
<select name="akt-miest" id="onoffaci">
<option value="a_0">Všetci</option>
<option value="a_1">Iba prihlásení</option>
<option value="a_5" selected="selected">Teraz na Pokeci</option>

<optgroup label="Hlavné miestnosti">

<option value="m_13">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bez záväzkov</option>
<option value="m_9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do pohody</option>
<option value="m_39">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dámsky klub</option>

</optgroup>
```

I use Html agility pack.

I try this:

```
 var selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("onoffaci");

 var nodes = selectNode.SelectNodes("option::*");
```

but I get error that xpath has invalid token. What is bad?

For example:

```
<option value="**a_0**">**Všetci**</option>
```

I need get value (a_0) and text Všetci.

So I try first access to select by Id:

Comment: Possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758644/parsing-html-with-html-agillity-pack

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem, several different XPath expressions you can use and explanation of their meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try this:
>
> ```
> var selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("onoffaci");   
> var nodes = selectNode.SelectNodes("option::*");
> ```
>
> but I get error that xpath has invalid
>   token. What is bad?

**The obvious problem is the use of**

`option::*`

`option::*` means: All nodes in the "option" axis. However there is no "option axis in XPath"

**You want**:

```
option
```

This selects all `option` elements that are children of the current node.

**You can write this in a single XPath expression** and omit the `getElementbyId()` call:

```
//select[@id='onoffaci']/option

For example:

    <option value="**a_0**">**Všetci**</option>

I need get value (a_0) and text Všetci
```

**Use**:

```
    //select[@id='onoffaci']/option/@value 
|
    //select[@id='onoffaci']/option/text()
```

This selects all `value` attributes of all `option` elements that are children of all `select` elements in the XML document that have an `id` attribute with value `'onoffaci'` and also all text nodes of all `option` elements that are children of all `select` elements in the XML document that have an `id` attribute with value `'onoffaci'`.

You will need to iterate the results to get the `@value` and `text()` for each `option` element.

Or:

```
    //select[@id='onoffaci']/option[1]/@value 
|
    //select[@id='onoffaci']/option[1]/text()
```

Here you use the observation that the `option` element you are interested in is the first `option` child of its parent — now this selects only the `value` attribute and the text nodes of the wanted `option` element.

Comment: Я благодарю вас за вашу помощь и подробные объяснения. я плохо говорят на русском :)

Comment: родным, а не "матерным" :) You've just said "Russian is not my obscene language". Sorry for taunting :)

Comment: @Flack: :)  This just proves what I said, doesn't it? :)  LOL