# HTML Agility Pack manipulating comments

Tags: knockout.js, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to open a master HTML file, then using basic StreamReaders to open helper files, read the contents, and put them in the right div in the master file.

It works, but for some reason some knockoutjs comment bindings are getting messed up.

Here's the html

```
<select data-bind="css: { 'required': isrequired }" class="answer-single">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: formquestionoptions -->
        <option data-bind="value:text, text:text"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->                              
</select>
```

(which I've verified in the Visual Studio debugger.)

When it gets inserted by HTML Agility Pack, this is what it looks like, which is causing Knockout errors

```
<select data-bind="css: { 'required': isrequired }" class="answer-single">
    <option value="">Choose
    <!-- ko foreach: formquestionoptions -->
        <option data-bind="value:text, text:text">
    <!-- /ko -->                              
</select>
```

How should I tell HTML Agility pack to...not do this?  Here's the current code

```
item.Helpers.ForEach(packet =>
{
    string contents = FileWriter.getFileContents(mapPath(packet.FileName));
    doc.GetElementbyId(packet.DomId).InnerHtml = Environment.NewLine + contents + Environment.NewLine;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default HAP treats option tags specially...so to turn this behavior off, here is the code you need

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759300/352552)