# HTML Agility Pack - Issue selecting an HTML select tag with the option tags within

Tags: c#, .net, dom, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack to select an element and return that element and everything it contains from an html string that is loaded.  In testing my code, I ran it against the select tag example from w3schools:

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
</select>
```

When I try to select and return this with HTML agility pack, I get (option closing tags removed):

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90
  <option value="saab">Saab 95
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK
  <option value="audi">Audi TT
</select>
```

So I did some searching here and found an instruction to add the line:
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");

I did that, and now I get (the options text is moved outside of the option tags):

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo"></option>Volvo XC90
  <option value="saab"></option>Saab 95
  <option value="mercedes"></option>Mercedes SLK
  <option value="audi"></option>Audi TT
</select>
```

I would like the output to match the original HTML.  What do I need to do to get that?

I was also playing with the OptionWriteEmptyNodes as when I tested with input tags their self closing was being removed, adding that option seemed to fix that.  I commented it out now to make sure it wasn't impacting this issue.

This is my .NET C# code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option"); // otherwise, the closing tag is removed.

//doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select");

if (nodes == null)
    return "Not found";
else
    return nodes[0].OuterHtml;
```

Comment: In your first example HTML code, your <select>-tag does not have the attribute name, are you saying that HAP is adding this?

Also, there is nothing about the model number in the first example, which your second has.

Please, edit your post to contain exactly what HTML you parse, and exactly what you want it to display instead of trying to describe it. Your explanations are making it more difficult that it seem to be.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the original example was different in different places.  I readded it using my html file.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the ElementsFlag field for the option tag to make it work

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["option"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

which should return your original HTML code.

I believe the reason that HtmlAgilityPack behaves this way is because the `<option>`-tag is *ironically* an optional tag in HTML that doesn't require a closing tag.

Taken from the documentation of the `HtmlNode` class and it's field `ElementsFlags`:

> Gets a collection of flags that define specific behaviors for specific
>   element nodes. The table contains a DictionaryEntry list with the
>   lowercase tag name as the Key, and a combination of HtmlElementFlags
>   as the Value.

Further look into the `HtmlElementFlag` enums reveal this:

> Empty - The node is empty. META or IMG are example of such nodes. 
>   Closed - The node will automatically be closed during parsing.

You can view the source code for the class [HtmlNode](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/1_4_0/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs) to see what other tags are considered 'specific'.

Comment: It works, thank you.  Also thank you for the information on where to look in the future.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out! There is a .CHM help file for HAP that can be downloaded here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925

Comment: This information is also available here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758644/parsing-html-with-html-agillity-pack