# Selecting Inner Text Using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract some inner text using HtmlAgilityPack.  Here is the HTML of interest:

```
<select name="Archives" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;Archives\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="Archives" style="width:200px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="Dashboard_Jul-2012">Dashboard_Jul-2012</option>
    <option value="Dashboard_Jun-2012">Dashboard_Jun-2012</option>
</select>
```

I am using:

```
string output = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString()
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(output);
string inner = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//option[@selected='selected']").InnerText;
```

but all I am getting is the empty string.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: did you try attribute or value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTMLAgilityPack by default leaves options tags empty (you can see the author's reason for this at [HtmlAgilityPack -- Does <form> close itself for some reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason)). To fix it, add this line before selecting the nodes:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option");
```

Comment: Thanks.  That would have taken me hours to figure out.

Comment: Genius. Saved hours of frustration.

Comment: To add a small clarification, the above code should be added before the `HtmlDocument` is loaded.