# Can HTMLAgility Pack leaves unclosed tags?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to parse a HTML string like this:

```
<widget attribute="1">
  <header>
    <table>
  </header>
  <item>
    <tr><td>content</td></tr>
  </item>
  <footer>
    </table>
  </footer>
</widget>
```

I'm using Html Agility Pack and I'm able to find all "widget":

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
doc.OptionOutputAsXml = false;
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString); 
HtmlNodeCollection widgets = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//widget");
```

My problem is when I try to get all childnodes of Widget node.. HTMLAgility closes automatically all my tags, so I'm not able to correctly retrieve Header, Item and Footer nodes. The output generated by Agility is:

```
<header>
    <table>
</table></header>
<item>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Riga n.1</p></td>
    </tr>
</item>
<footer>

</footer>
```

It closes Table tag in the Header, and hides the Table tag in the Footer. There is a way to leave these tag unclosed? I tried to search documentation about the logic of LoadHtml method but I didn't find anything. I think I need to play with Options.

Can you help me?

Comment: That's not an HTML string.

Comment: I know it's not a standard-compliant html string.. I need to parse it and THEN I will build dynamically standard html code. So I'm asking if there is a way to manage this type of code "exception" with HTMLAgility.

Answer (score 2):

Html Agility Pack does not generally support overlapping tags by design. However, you can tweak it like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("table", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap | HtmlElementFlag.Empty);
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
```

In this case, you instruct the library to treat TABLE as an overlapping tag. As a side note, FORM is the only TAG by default defined as an overlapping tag (see the reason here: [HtmlAgilityPack -- Does <form> close itself for some reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason)).

However, this does not come as a free lunch...

It means, the library will now see what's inside the table and closing table tags as a pure text element. So all the tags inside the parsed table will not be programmatically accessible, you won't see it in the DOM, you won't see it using XPATH, etc... but that may be enough for your needs.

Comment: @BoltClock - what's not valid HTML?

Comment: Your given HTML fragment that you describe as not valid XML or XHTML but valid HTML... it is not valid in any of the three languages.

Comment: @boltclock - Do you have any clear proof there is no HTML version prior to HTML 3.2 that tolerates it? I probably started to work with HTML 1.0 and my memory does not go that far

Comment: SGML considers overlapping tags like `<b><i></b></i>` incorrect (I imagine this applies to all versions of HTML, including ones that implement SGML; i.e. everything before HTML5). I don't have ISO 8879 handy, but [this part of the HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html) implies that proper nesting of tags is an attribute of SGML syntax that carries over to HTML < 5 in general.

Comment: I cite wikipedia: 'The design of HTML was ... inspired by SGML tagging, but, since no clear expansion and parsing guidelines were established, most actual HTML documents are not valid SGML documents'. Indeed, browsers do support tags overlap (for character formatting tags only of course) for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack parses HTML. This is completely broken HTML, so it takes a best guess. Browsers will fare no better. For instance, Firefox translates this as:

```
<header>
<item> </item>
<footer> </footer>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</header>
```

By using broken HTML, you're opening yourself up to undefined behaviour that will be implementation specific. Fix your HTML and restore sense to the world.

Comment: Hi spender.. my HTML has sense.. I need to create a standard html output with a Template widget, like it.

e.g. the Widget will show a list of news, so I would like to build the output using that code. Then, I can write to the response output something like this:

<table>
<tr><td>News 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>News 2</td></tr>
</table>

I hope you can understand better what I wanted to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove those `<>` symbols from your values, then you can `XDocument.Parse()` it:

```
<widget attribute="1">
    <header>[table]</header>
    <item>[tr][td]content[/td][/tr]</item>
    <footer>[/table]</footer>
</widget>
```

Just `.Replace('[','<').Replace(']', '>')` what you read and you should be good to go.

[Italian MSDN page about System.Xml.Linq.XDocument class here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)