# Html Agility Pack xPath issue

Tags: parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am developping a .Net console application.
I want to request an HTML page and then pick up some data inside.
I use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to build an object model from the response HTML page and to select nodes by using xPath.

Here is an extract of the response HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <div class="conteneur">
        <!-- ... -->
        <div class="page">
            <div class="inter_page">
                <!-- ... -->
                <form action="missions.html" method="post" id="formliste">
                <table class="tbl_deco_mini" cellspacing="0" style="width: 30%; margin: 0px;">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="td">
                            <div class="inliste">
                                <p class="ligne_epee">
                                    <a id="3"></a><a href="http://ffta.mimigyaru.com/missions,affiche_001-moisson-dherbe.html#3"
                                        class="simple">
                                        <img src="http://ffta.mimigyaru.com/medias/divers/mission_batail.png" alt="Moisson d'herbe"
                                            class="img_middle" title="Moisson d'herbe" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://ffta.mimigyaru.com/missions,affiche_001-moisson-dherbe.html#3">001-Moisson
                                                d'herbe</a>
                                </p>
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to select the `<table>` node which is the first child of the `<form>` node.
I have written the following code :

```
HtmlDocument l_missionsDoc = new HtmlDocument();
l_missionsDoc.Load(l_stream);

XPathNavigator l_navigator = l_missionsDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator l_iterator = l_navigator.Select("//form[@id='formliste']/table");

if (l_iterator.Count <= 0) continue;
```

`l_iterator.Count` is equal to 0 but it must be equal to 1.
What is wrong with my xPath selection ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the FORM tag has a special treatment by the HTML Agility Pack. The reasons are described here: [HtmlAgilityPack -- Does <form> close itself for some reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason)

So, you basically need to remove that special treatment, like this (must happen *before* any load):

```
// instruct the library to treat FORM like any other tag
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

HtmlDocument l_missionsDoc = new HtmlDocument();
l_missionsDoc.Load(l_stream);

XPathNavigator l_navigator = l_missionsDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator l_iterator = l_navigator.Select("//form[@id='formliste']/table");

if (l_iterator.Count <= 0) continue;
```