# Add form tag around a body tag using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How do I add a form tag around a HMLDocument?

For the given HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Full name: <input name="FullName" type="text" value=""></p> 
  <p><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the following code...

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
doc.LoadHtml(input);
var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@action]") == null)
{
    var form = doc.CreateElement("form");
    form.Attributes.Add("action", "/pages/event/10302");
    body.PrependChild(form);
}
return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

I get back the following, notice we don't have a closing `</form>` tag above the closing `</body>` tag

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="/pages/event/10302">
  <p>Full name: <input name="FullName" type="text" value=""></p> 
  <p><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FORM element has a special treatment. See here on SO for more: [HtmlAgilityPack -- Does <form> close itself for some reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason)

So, you could do this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form"); // remove special handling for FORM
doc.LoadHtml(input);
var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@action]") == null)
{
    var form = doc.CreateElement("form");
    form.Attributes.Add("action", "/pages/event/10302");
    body.PrependChild(form);
}
```

but it will get you this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="/pages/event/10302"></form>
  <p>Full name: <input name="FullName" type="text" value=""></p> 
  <p><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Which is logical, you don't surround anything in that new form. So, instead you can do this:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(input);
var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@action]") == null)
{
    var form = body.CloneNode("form", true);
    form.Attributes.Add("action", "/pages/event/10302");
    body.ChildNodes.Clear();
    body.PrependChild(form);
}
```

which will get you this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body><form action="/pages/event/10302">
  <p>Full name: <input name="FullName" type="text" value=""></p>
  <p><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </form></body>
</html>
```

This is not the only way, but it works, and you don't necessarily have to remove the FORM special treatment.