# HtmlAgilityPack C#: Remove node with with all childerns

Tags: c#, html

I have html document and I want to remove "form" tag with all its child element.

```
        var nodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//form");
        int attributeRemoveCount = 0;

        if (nodeCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode link in nodeCollection)
            {
                link.Remove();
            }
        }
```

my html is similar to

```
<form name="LPHitCountForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="LPHitCount" value="0">
</form>
```

Above code just remove "" this line from html.
below tags are remain same.
Hence final html becomes as below.

```
  <input type="hidden" name="LPHitCount" value="0">
</form>
```

I have tried RemoveAll function also but is not working.
Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to special handling of `form` and other tags in the library. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218847/htmlagilitypack-does-form-close-itself-for-some-reason) for an explanation.

Here's a quick way to fix this:

```
//Do this before using the library.
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```