# HtmlAgilityPack Windows Phone 8.1 Find node in htmlDocument

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am building a Windows 8.1 Phone app which needs to access elements from a web page. The elements I need to access are fairly deep inside the page so I need to find a simple way to access those elements without using XPATH (because XPATH is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1 to my understanding).

The method below is the method I am using to get the page (which works correctly) as far as loading the document from the web page is concerned. To give you an example HTML element I will need to access, consider the following example:

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="2">
            <p>The text I wish to access</p>
        </div>
        <div class="3"></div>
    </form>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the method I need to access the text

```
private async Task GetHtmlDocument(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = new LoginCredentials().Credentials;

    try
    {
        WebResponse myResponse = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        htmlDoc.Load(myResponse.GetResponseStream());


        var body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("body").First();
        var form = body.Descendants("form").First();

    }
    catch (...){ ... }
}
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that `Descendants("form")` is returning nothing useful (even though `body.InnerHTML` contains a form element).

The following code prints all of the HTML code which can be found by inspecting the Body element in the browser for "body", but for "form" `InnerHtml` is empty ("") and the element has no children.

```
HtmlNode body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("body")
            .FirstOrDefault();
HtmlNode form = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("body")
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Descendants("form")
            .FirstOrDefault();

Debug.WriteLine(body.InnerHtml);
Debug.WriteLine(form.InnerHtml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219060/1279342) will help you. Apparently you need to remove  from the flagged element list.