# HtmlAgilityPack SelectSingleNode returns an HtmlNode without InnerHtml

Tags: c#, html, dom, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm a bit confused about SelectSingleNode method. 
I'm passing to it a simple xpath expression and expect to get the node with full content, with all nested nodes, but actually retrieve just a html tag what I was looking for without any inner and outer text, and the node does not contain any childs.

Xpath:

```
//form
```

Here is the html:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://test.com/action">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="attribute1" VALUE="some value"/>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="attribute2" VALUE="another value"/>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And there is a method:

```
    public List<Parameter> CollectFilledInputsFromResponseForm(IRestResponse response, string formXpath)
    {
        var responseAsHtml = new HtmlDocument();
        responseAsHtml.LoadHtml(response.Content);
        var formDoc = responseAsHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(formXpath);

        if (formDoc == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No form found for '.{0}' xPath", formXpath));

        var formHtml = new HtmlDocument();
        formHtml.LoadHtml(formDoc.OuterHtml);
        var inputs = formHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input");

        var parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            var name = input.GetAttributeValue("name", "Name not found");
            var value = input.GetAttributeValue("value", "Value not found");

            if (name.Equals("Name not found") || value.Equals("Value not found"))
                continue;

            parameters.Add(new Parameter(){Name = name,Value = value,Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost});
        }

        return parameters;
    }
```

[image: Locals Screenshot]

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");` before loading the document

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219060/4033466