# GetElementsByTagName in Htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack, getelementsbytagname

How do I select an element for e.g. textbox if I don't know its id?

If I know its id then I can simply write:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = doc.GetElementbyId(id);
```

But I don't know textbox's ID and I can't find GetElementsByTagName method in HtmlagilityPack which is available in webbrowser control.
In web browser control I could have simply written:

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = browser[i].Document.GetElementsByTagName("form");
foreach (HtmlElement currentElement in elements)
{

}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML form I am talking about

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="/test.php">
<input name="sometext" type="text">
</form>
```

Please note I don't know the ID of form. And there can be several forms on same page. The only thing I know is "sometext" and I want to get this element using just this name. So I guess I will have to parse all forms one by one and then find this name "sometext" but how do I do that?

Comment: well, what does the html look like? there might be another way.

Comment: @shriek
I have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3120867/68607

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're looking for the tag by its tagName (such as `form` for `<form name="someForm">`), then you can use:

```
var forms = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("form");
```

If you're looking for the tag by its name property (such as `someForm` for `<form name="someForm">`, then you can use:

```
var forms = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(node => node.Name == "formName");
```

For the last one you could create a simple extension method:

```
public static class HtmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetElementsByName(this HtmlNode parent, string name)
    {
        return parent.Descendants().Where(node => node.Name == name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> GetElementsByTagName(this HtmlNode parent, string name)
    {
        return parent.Descendants(name);
    }
}
```

Note: You can also use `SelectNodes` and XPath to query your document:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form//input");
```

Would give you all inputs on the page that are in a form tag.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[1]//input");
```

Would give you all the inputs of the first form on the page

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("....");

var inputs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["name"]!=null && n.Attributes["name"].Value == "sometext")
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @jessehouwing while i was preparing the answer, OP hadn't edited the question and the attribute was unknown.

Comment: @jessehouwing No I won't think of it too much for just a few lines of html OP has shown. I just showed the way and don't think to write OP's full code.

Comment: @jessehouwing I can not say that I am much interested in how you answer the questions. If you have something better to say than write as an answer. This is my way.

Answer (score 6):

Any node by name:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@name='name']")
```

Input nodes by name:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@name='name']")
```